# Online PDE course

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I want to teach myself [PDE](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Partial_differential_equation). I am asking here because I am mainly interested in applications in electromagnetism / optics.

I would like to have a nice series of online lectures.
I would also appreciate some recommendation on a textbook, for which solution manual can be found somewhere.

Comment: Would [math.se] be a better home for this question?

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PLGCj8f6sgswntUil8yzohR_qazOfYZCg_

This may interest you.

Comment: What exactly do you mean by PDE? Unlike ODE, this is such a huge subject that "studying PDE" is not very well-defined. For the most part PDE do not have explicit solutions, and even when they do, these explicit solutions often do not give as much qualitative information as more subtle arguments. Many PDE do not have solutions in the strong sense (i.e. in the sense that the solution has all derivatives appearing in the equation and the equation is satisfied at each point). So there is a difficulty with specifying a different notion of solution, which has both mathematical and modeling issues.

Comment: Given a notion of solution, there is still a major question about existence/uniqueness. Given existence/uniqueness (to the extent that we have it), a lot of problems, especially evolution problems, have questions about regularity (continuity/existence of derivatives). There are more problem-specific questions (things like symmetry and so forth) that can be asked. Then numerical issues get started, etc. My point is, there is a lot to be said, and not all of it is said in any one place.

Comment: I asked this question in physics stackexchange originally because I wanted to learn things that will be useful for more advanced electromagnetism studies. I do not know exactly which subjects would be beneficial for me, which is why I am asking for recommendations.

Comment: Apart from the reccomended youtube playlists which are good, Peter J. Olver's Introduction to PDE is a thorough start to the topic. It is available here http://chaosbook.org/library/Olver14.pdf

Answer (score 2):

There is a good playlist of videos here: https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PLF6061160B55B0203

Further, MIT Opencourseware has some excellent PDE courses, but no videos. Many have full lecture notes, exams and solutions, assignments etc. See here for example, and explore their site: http://ocw.mit.edu/courses/mathematics/18-152-introduction-to-partial-differential-equations-fall-2011/

They'll also have good book recommendations.

ETA:

This is another great MOOC, that also references the videos I first suggested, has good book recommendations and plenty of PDFs etc. https://legacy.saylor.org/ma222/Intro/